# Beginner issues grabbing HREF from Python BeautifulSoup involving list comprehension

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I've narrowed the HTML down to a point with my code, but I'm having trouble using list comprehension to grab the href addresses.

Here's my code (BASE_URL and STEM_URL are fixed address):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(BASE_URL).text)
divyclass = soup.find("div", {"class":"node-inner"}).tbody
```

where i run into issues and I get this error (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`) is when I add this line for list comprehension:

```
links = [STEM_URL + row.a["href"] for row in divyclass.findAll("td")]
```

When I run

```
for row in divyclass.findAll("td"):
    print row
```

, I get this output btw, just so you can see where I'm pulling the a hrefs from:

```
<td align="center" class="tableheader" colspan="4" valign="middle">NBA Drafts</td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"> </td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"> </td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"> </td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"><a href="/nba_final_draft/2014">2014</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"> <a href="/nba_final_draft/2013">2013</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"> <a href="/nba_final_draft/2012">2012</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"><a href="/nba_final_draft/2011">2011</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle"><a href="/nba_final_draft/2010">2010</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_final_draft/2009">2009</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2008.html">2008</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2007.html">2007</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2006.html">2006</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2005.html">2005</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2004.html">2004</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2003.html">2003</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2002.html">2002</a></td>
<td align="center" class="text" valign="middle" width="25%"><a href="/nba_draft_history/2001.html">2001</a></td>
```

gah! i just wanna pull the hrefs!! thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2):

For the rows with no `a` elements in them, `row.a` will be `None`. If you change

```
links = [STEM_URL + row.a["href"] for row in divyclass.findAll("td")]
```

to

```
links = [STEM_URL + row.a["href"] for row in divyclass.findAll("td") if row.a]
```

that will filter out the `row` elements with no `a` elements.

Comment: thanks @Misandrist! is there any reason why `row.a["href"] = True` wouldn't have worked? And is there any alternative that would've worked?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: `row.a["href"] = True` will raise basically the same `TypeError` if `row.a` is `None`. You can't index a `None` object to set values any more than you can get to get values; it's not a collection.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: Also, why would you want to do that? Then, instead of getting just the actual `href` strings, you'd get a mix of `href` strings and useless `True` boolean values.

Comment: makes sense guys. @abarnert and @Misandrist - if I wanted to grab just those numbers after the href tags so that I could add another conditional, how would I go about that?

i.e.

`links = [STEM_URL + row.a["href"] for row in divyclass.findAll("td") if row.a and int(row.a["href"].text) >= 2010]` this doesn't work as str object has no text attribute?

Comment: update:
i've discovered using this instead, but it won't compare for some of the addresses further down that aren't just number values between the a tags (i.e. 1980-1989). What's the best way to deal with those exceptions?
`if row.a and int(row.a.contents[0]) >= 2010]`